# Not able to show text with new line in textarea, how to preserve them?

Tags: php, mysql, function, nl2br

I have a problem with text that have new lines..
I insert text in my database like this:

```
$descrizionetipologia = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descrtipologia']);
//insert query
```

and I take it from the database with

```
 $descrizionetipologia=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"CA_DescrTipologia");
 //and I have to show it in a textarea with a javascript function.
 document.EDITform.EDITdescrtipologia.value="<?php echo $descrizionetipologia; ?>";
```

When I set the value of my textarea with $descrizionetipologia, the textarea don't show anything if the text have newline...
I added nl2br , mysql_real_escape_string, but I have a lot of confusion about these functions...

if, when I want to show it, I use

```
$descrizionetipologia=str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"),"",nl2br(htmlentities($descrizionetipologia)));
```

I see

```
PROVA <br> PROVA
```

but I don't want this...I want the text with new line... I want see

```
PROVA
PROVA
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the textArea's value - that ignores newlines as whitespace. Instead set the innerHTML property.

```
document.EDITForm.EDITdescrtipologia.innerHTML = "<?php echo addslashes ($descrizionetipologia); ?>";
```

(addslashes in case it contains quotes). That should do the trick.

Comment: This don't work. In the textarea I don't see anything :/

Comment: What does the generated javascript look like? What errors, if any, does the debug engine in your browser show?

Comment: Alternatively, try setting innerText although most browsers can handle either.

Comment: The problem is that anything is passed setting .innerHTML
by the way, I solved the problem using post method to take datas instead of javascript  and no more problem with characters, new lines etc..
But thank you for your help :)